# Leafletjs create plain map with no icons and other data

Tags: leaflet

I am new to leafletjs. I created a basic map but it is full of names, icons and other data and I want to see only the roads and the buildings whithout numbers or names. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CartoDB instead of osm layer.

```
var CartoDB_VoyagerNoLabels = 
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    maxZoom: 20
});
```

Take a look at this webpage https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/. Maybe you'll find a style that will suit better for your map.
P.S. If you want to have the ability to customize the base map fully - consider using Mapbox instead of Leaflet.

Comment: any way i can keep the names of the roads?

Comment: You can add another layer on top of CartoDB
`var CartoDB_PositronOnlyLabels = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
 attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
 subdomains: 'abcd',
 maxZoom: 20
});`